# How to set env variables and run multiple commands with PsExec?

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt, environment-variables, perforce, pstools

How can I run multiple commands with PsExec, and how can I export environment variables?

I can run two commands by doing the below, but when I try to export an environment variable the second command errors out.

Running two commands:

```
psexec \\servername cmd /c p4 info & dir
```

^ This works

Trying to export env variable and then run another command:

```
psexec \\servername cmd /c set P4PORT=xx.xxx.xx.xx & p4 -c client -P ################## -u user diff -f //dir/dir2/dir3/...
```

^ This errors out on the second command, it complains about the client spec name I'm passing in, but it runs fine if i run just the second command. It's like the first command throws off the second.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will find the second command is running on the local machine, not the remote one.  You need to use quote marks like this:

```
psexec \\servername cmd /c "p4 info & dir"
```

Comment: perfect, this did it!

Comment: Worked for me, too.  Thank you!